# How to make HTTPS call in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

my requirement is to make a secured web request call to an external site and process the message returned. A basic authentication is required from this external website. I passed in credential in my proxy service via property "Proxy-Authorization" as suggested here https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Enabling+HTTP+Basic+Authentication+through+a+Proxy+Server.

This document also suggests to configure http.proxyHost/http.proxyPort for  in axis2.xml.  However, I don't have a proxy server.  Should I leave this configuration out?  When I did configure http.proxyHost/http.proxyPort as suggested to localhost:8080, I also see the following exception in the log file.  So I am wondering if I configured the ESB correctly for a secured Web service call?  Greatly appreciate it for any help you can provide.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-10-24 13:08:17,471]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_CODE : 0 {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-10-24 13:08:17,471]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_MESSAGE : Cache-Control:private,Content-Length:58,Content-Type:text/html,Date:Mon, 24 Oct 2016 18:09:37 GMT,WWW-Authenticate:BASIC Realm=hostname,X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-10-24 13:08:17,471]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_DETAIL : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Cache-Control:private,Content-Length:58,Content-Type:text/html,Date:Mon, 24 Oct 2016 18:09:37 GMT,WWW-Authenticate:BASIC Realm=hostname,X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.handleException(Axis2Sender.java:257)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:225)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:531)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:118)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:337)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:261)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport out has not been set
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:432)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:222)
... 14 more
{org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since WSO2 ESB is not behind a firewall you don't need to set the Proxy-Authorization header.You can use header mediator to set the Authorization header in the proxy service as follows.`<header name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ',base64Encode('<username>:<password>'))" scope="transport"/>`.
Please find more details in [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Header+Mediator#HeaderMediator-Example2-HTTPheaders) and [here](http://nuwanwimalasekara.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-add-http-basic-authentication.html).